# Moving "vendor/" in a different location and symlinking it breaks drush

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I'd like to have `vendor/` moved out of the Drupal 8 root and symlink it. Composer doesn't have any problem with that (all commands work) but when I issue any `drush` command, even `drush --version`, it breaks.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev website --stability dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist
$ cd website
$ mv vendor ..
$ ln -s ../vendor vendor
$ drush --version

PHP Warning:  require(/tmp/test1/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /tmp/test1/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/tmp/test1/vendor/composer/../../load.environment.php' (include_path='/tmp/test1/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/tmp/test1/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/tmp/test1/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/tmp/test1/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/usr/share/php') in /tmp/test1/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 70
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/raw/eMDgkdHV

Can I achieve this somehow? Even if I need to temporarily edit some path in an autoloader php script.

I need to do this on the vagrant based dev environment where I'd like to pull `vendor/` out of the synced folder which is very very slow.

Comment: Drupal root normally lives inside /web, so /vendor already is outside the Drupal root. When moving vendor you also need to fix the autoloader. Moving vendor outside the project root probably is no good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it via specifying an absolute path in the `vendor-dir` configuration of `composer.json`: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir